# neo4j rest api delete example

Tags: neo4j

Currently i am using the Transactional HTTP endpoint to delete all the nodes and the relations. I am able to do it using the browser. But when i do the same the statement is not getting committed. Below is the way i am trying to achieve it.

```
URI: http://xyz:7479/db/data/transaction
```

Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json

```
{   "statements" : [ {     "statement" : "MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r"     } ] }
```

Response: `{"commit":"http://xyz:7479/db/data/transaction/172/commit","results":[{"columns":[],"data":[]}],"transaction":{"expires":"Mon, 15 Sep 2014 14:15:31 +0000"},"errors":[]}`

Can you please let me know whether i am doing it right ? and why the nodes are not getting deleted ? Or is there any other alternative way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like you are trying to delete the nodes using transactional endpoint. This is ok, but you have to commit the transaction in order for the changes to take effect. The commit URL is send back to you with the response (`http://xyz:7479/db/data/transaction/172/commit` in your example). It is different for each transaction, so you have to issue a request with the exact same URL which was send back to you.

You can avoid sending the second request to commit the transaction just by adding `/commit` to your original URL:

```
http://xyz:7479/db/data/transaction/commit
```

This will cause the transaction to start and commit within single request. You can read about it [in the manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html).

---

**EDIT: As mentioned by others the endpoint described below is DEPRECATED:**

Having said that, the transaction is usually only for complex use cases (with at least two queries when one depends on the other). In your example there seem to be no need for a transaction. You can use plain old `/db/data/cypher` endpoint as described [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html).

Your request body could look like this:

```
{
  "query" : "MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r",
  "params" : {}
}
```

Just remember to add `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers.

Comment: the request body which you mentioned is deprecated as per the documents. I am doing a complex query i just took out a the part of it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by @Maciej, the uri should finish with /commit.

BTW the body is not right, this one is for the deprecated cypher endpoint.

It should contain something similar to this :

{
  "statements": [ {"statement": "MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE r,n" } ] 
}

Please refer to the documentation :

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request

Comment: Oh, you are right. I've been using it for a long time. Since when it is deprecated?

Comment: @christophe : with the /commit it works fine but when it comes to run the statement in a transaction even after commit it is not working

Comment: @MaciejSz Since 2.1.* I think

Comment: @Sandeep.Mulawad Can you parse the curl request being sent ?

Comment: @Sandeep.Mulawad what you mean running the statement after a commit ? if the transaction is commited you need to open a new one or use the open&commit as described.

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen : I was able to successfully do it. Actually i was missing the post data in the commit request.